# Declension is a noun. What is the verb?

Tags: verbs, nouns, grammatical-number, american-english, british-english

Based on Wikipedia article, in linguistics, declension is the inflection of nouns, pronouns, adjectives, and articles to indicate number (at least singular and plural), case (nominative or subjective, genitive or possessive, etc.), and gender.

Declension is a noun. What is a proper verb to say "I want to say different words that appeared from the word day - days, daily etc". How to say it in one word in English?

Comment: To *[decline](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/decline)*: (grammar) to state or list the inflections of (a noun, adjective, or pronoun), or (of a noun, adjective, or pronoun) to be inflected for number, case, or gender Compare conjugate (sense 1) [Collins]

Comment: A verb approaches a noun at a bar.  "Hey baby, wanna come back to my place and conjugate?"  "I decline."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The verb corresponding to declension is *decline*. However, your example of *day - daily* is not an example of declension. It is an example of word formation (with the adverbial suffix -ly). Declension adds/changes inflections, not suffixes.

And here's a little on-topic joke I came across recently:

> A verb walks up to a noun in a bar:
>
> --  Hey, babe, wanna go back to my place and conjugate?
>
> -- I decline.

Comment: Inflections are nearly always affixes, so I don't get the point you're trying to make.

Comment: His point is that many inflections are affixes, but not all affixes are inflections. Daily's *-ly* happens to be an affix that is not an inflection.